# How to assign dynamic variable value to global variable in ftl?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, freemarker

Below is my sample code snippet. Global variable should hold the token value. Each time the token changes dynamically. How to assign that token value to global variable, or any other way to access that token?

```
csrf_token_name = resetToken()+"#";    
csrf_param = csrf_token_name + " " + csrf_token;    
<#global csrf_param= (csrf_param) // Expected to be assign>    
function resetToken()     
{    
 var token = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,12);     
 return token;    
}
```

Comment: Are you mixing JavaScript and FreeMarker? FreeMarker can't read JavaScript variables.

Comment: is it possible wit ajax?

Comment: You could send variables to the server in the data of your ajax request, but that's how you would do it in any templating language (or even plain HTML).